# How to adjust vertical scroll position of DataGridView to show entire last row after changing its height?

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll

I have a DataGridView that normally shows a single line of data per row. But when the user enters a cell, I increase the minimum height to make editing easier. However, when this happens for the last row in the grid, the vertical scroll position does not get adjusted, and only the top of the row is visible, which often causes it to appear blank. Setting FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex to the index of that row doesn't fix this.

Here's my code:

```
protected override void OnCellEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnCellEnter(e);

    // Looks weird, but this solves an annoying problem where the wait cursor gets stuck
    // on randomly after displaying one of the segmentation dialogs.
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008958/datagridview-retains-waitcursor-when-updated-from-thread/13808474#13808474
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    EditMode = (GetIgnoreStateForRow(CurrentCellAddress.Y)) ? DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically : DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 || CurrentCellAddress.Y < 0 || (!Focused && (EditingControl == null || !EditingControl.Focused)))
    {
        var minHeight = RowTemplate.Height * 3;
        if (CurrentRow != null && CurrentRow.Height < minHeight)
            CurrentRow.MinimumHeight = minHeight;
        return;
    }
    SchedulePlaybackForCell();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer. It's not necessarily as elegant as I'd hoped for, since it requires overriding another method, thus separating the "fix" from the "problem". But it does seem to work:

```
    protected override void OnRowHeightChanged(DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRowHeightChanged(e);
        if (CurrentRow == e.Row && e.Row.Index == RowCount - 1)
            FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.Row.Index;
    }
```